# Android R.java disappeared after reference to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, r.java-file

I followed the instructions by the facebook, everything is good before adding reference to the facebook library. As mentioned in the title, the R.java just disappeared, making the whole project unable to run.

I tried to delete the gen folder, cleaned the project, rebuilt it, but it did no good.

The project runs without facebook, but I have to implement the facebook function to get the project done. Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

it is probably that there are now two R.java, one in your project and the other one in facebook. Try to manually put the import back, like, com.yourpackage.R and see if that fixes the problem.